# Append mysql query results to a variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

I have a query that I am executing, the results are being fetched as a variable $result.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

There are 15 elements in the array. 0-15.

I want to echo out a radio button for each item in the array. I want to assign each item to the "Value" field on the radio button (below is what i am currently doing.)

```
    foreach( $result as $row ) {

         echo '<h4><input type="radio" name="inputWalls" id="radioclick" value="'.$row['batch'].'" >'.$row['batch']. '</h4>'; 

    }
```

what happens right now is that all the items in the array print out along with all the radio buttons next to them which is what i want. However, only the first radio button stores the value for the first element in the array.

Below is a var_dump() of the array.

```
array (size=15)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002128.RGB' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002128.RGB' (length=12)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002129.RIE' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002129.RIE' (length=12)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002130.RGB' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002130.RGB' (length=12)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002131.RIE' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002131.RIE' (length=12)
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002132.RGB' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002132.RGB' (length=12)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002133.RIE' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002133.RIE' (length=12)
  6 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002134.RIE' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002134.RIE' (length=12)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002135.RGB' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002135.RGB' (length=12)
  8 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002136.RGB' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002136.RGB' (length=12)
  9 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002137.RIE' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002137.RIE' (length=12)
  10 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002139.RGB' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002139.RGB' (length=12)
  11 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002140.RGB' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002140.RGB' (length=12)
  12 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002141.RIE' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002141.RIE' (length=12)
  13 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002142.RIE' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002142.RIE' (length=12)
  14 => 
    array (size=2)
      'batch' => string 'B0002143.RGB' (length=12)
      0 => string 'B0002143.RGB' (length=12)
```

This is the jquery code which shows the information as an alert of what each radio button contains.

```
$(function(){
    $("#radioclick").click(function() {     
        alert($("input[name=inputWalls]:checked").val());
    });
});
```

When i select the first radio button, it shows the value B0002128.RGB which is the first element in the array. every other radio button holds no value as nothing is printed. Long post, but i would appreciate the help.

Comment: If the `batch` value is printed aside the radio button, is is too in the value attribute, since your PHP looks ok. I think your problem is on how to verify this. Show how you do this: *i select the first radio button, it shows the value»*.

Comment: See above jquery at the end of the post. When i click a radio button, it prints out the value as an alert popup. Only the firstradio button prints out an alert. Maybe the jquery code is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** use the same `id` multiple times.

The problem is the use of `id="radioclick"` in a loop.

So `$("#radioclick").click(function() {` will trigger on the first matching `id` it finds... But not all.

Use a `class` instead.

Comment: Wow. as simple as that! worked straight away. Cheers :)

Comment: You could also shorten `alert($("input[name=inputWalls]:checked").val());` to `alert($(this).val());` ;)

Answer (score 0):

the ID of an HTML element must be unique. You are assigning the same id to each `<input>` element so when you bind the click function it only gets bound to the first element.

Use `class="radioclick"` instead of `id="radioclick"` in your HTML and `$(".radioclick").click` instead of `$("#radioclick").click` in your JS.